# How do I write a loop function as a recursive function?

Tags: c++, recursion

Well, I've been trying to rework this many times. Though, at one point I thought the longestSequence function would help, since it displays the longest hailstone sequence. Though, I can't seem to figure out how to find, or store the value it used to find that.If someone could explain how, I would appreciate it.

```
int longestSequence(int n)
{
    int u = n;

    if(u == 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        return max(hailstoneLength(u), longestSequence(u-1));
    }
}
```

The part I'm having trouble with is my longest start sequence:

```
int hailLongestSeq(int n)
{
    int k;
    int longest = 0;
    for(int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
    {
        if(hailstoneLength(j) > longest)
        {
            longest = hailstoneLength(j);
            k = j;
        }
    }
    return k;   
}
```

I'm not sure how to make this into a recursion, I noticed for some recursions I saw people using for loops still, but I was sure we weren't supposed to use loops.
It may be a dumb question, but is there a formula to translating for loops to recursions, if anyone knows one?

The expected out put is like this:

The longest hailstone sequence starting with a number up to 10 has length 20.
The longest hailstone sequence starting with a number up to 10 begins with 9.

as 9's sequence has a length of 20 numbers, and is the longest from 1 to 10.

Comment: Didn't you ask this yesterday?

Comment: the formula is reword the problem in terms of sub problems: example: a for loop of n iterations is an iteration over a for loop of n-1 iterations

Comment: No I didn't ask this yesterday. I submitted this at 1 am today

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes every for loop can be translated to recursive call, obviously like this:

```
for (i=0; i<N; i++) {
  body;
}
```

translate it to:

```
func(int i) {
  if (i<N) { body; func(i+1) }
  else return;
}

func(0);
```

This can be easily extended to any for loop computation (add parameters if needed, return value, etc).

Comment: Wow. Thanks! I'm still learning C++. I should probably save this in case I need it again.

Comment: When i do this I'm gettign a segmentation fault. How do I fix that? or am I doign anythign wrog?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the local variables who's value you want to retain in the parameter signature of the function. I have tried to rewrite the code as recursive. Check and verify if this solves your problem.

```
int hailLongestSeq(int n, int j, int k, int longest)
{
    if(j <= n)
    {
        if(hailstoneLength(j) > longest)
        {
            longest = hailstoneLength(j);
            k = j;
        }
        k = hailLongestSeq(n, ++j, k, longest);
    }
    return k;   
}
```

This may need a fix, however the logic remains the same, pass the variables as parameter to retain the value.

Comment: Same with this, I'm gettign a segmentation fault

Comment: Sorry I acidentally added j++ instead of ++j that was resulting in infinite loop. I have modified the code now. Can you check again and confirm if it is working for you.

Comment: Oh yes, it works Rishabh, thanks. Thanks, and if it's alright, is it alright if I can get an explanation on how this works? I'm working through more hand simulations.

Comment: Well honestly, I just converted your loop logic to recursion. First thing to convert loop is to create a condition based on your loop condition. If the condition is satisfied then call the function again, else return the output. Also make sure that all the local variables used in the function are passed as parameter while making a recursive call. For complex tasks I always find it better to write loops first and then convert it to recursive functions. Keep practising. Please upvote if you got the point.

Comment: I understand that pretty well now, Though sorry, I can't upvote as i dont have 15 rep, but I noticed it was also explained above. When i followed their way it resulted the same. Thanks again.